# Android force close: could not find newChooseAccountIntent

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I'm working on an Android application and I'm running into some issues. I created an app engine connected Android app. The back-end is deployed, and I am adding authentication to an endpoint. the code compiles with no errors and launches on my device but it force closes when I press a button to go to a registration activity. I checked Logcat and it said:

> could not find method
>   com.Google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.GMs.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.newChooseAccountIntent,
>   referenced by RegistrationActivity.chooseAccount

What can I do to resolve this?

PromoterRegistrationActivity

```
package com.theincrowd;


import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import  com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.theincrowd.promoterendpoint.Promoterendpoint;
import com.theincrowd.promoterendpoint.model.Promoter;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class PromoterRegistrationActivity extends Activity {

static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1;
static final String PREF_AUTH_TOKEN = "authToken";

//credentials
GoogleAccountCredential credential;

//Shared Preferences and preferred user
SharedPreferences settings;
String accountName;

boolean signedIn = false;

Promoterendpoint service;

//text fields and button stuff
EditText fn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstName); 
EditText ln = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastName);
EditText org = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
Button regBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regButton);

private String firstName = fn.getText().toString();
private String lastName = ln.getText().toString();
private String organization = org.getText().toString();
private String emailAddress = email.getText().toString();



//this method gets data from the text fields and populates an instance of the Promoter model
protected void CreateNewPromoter(){
    Promoter nuPromoter = new Promoter();
    nuPromoter.setFirstName(firstName);
    nuPromoter.setLastName(lastName);
    nuPromoter.setOrganization(organization);
    nuPromoter.setEmail(emailAddress);
    new CreateNewPromoterTask().execute(nuPromoter);

}

//class writes new promoters to the datastore
private class CreateNewPromoterTask extends AsyncTask<Promoter, Void, Void>{
    //
    protected Void doInBackground(Promoter... nuPromoters){
        try{
            service.insertPromoter(nuPromoters[0]).execute();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}

//Include methods for setSelectedAccountName and the account picker
public void signedIn(View v){
    if(!this.signedIn){
        chooseAccount();
    }else {
        forgetAccount();
    }
}
//account picker. here lies my problem... 
private void chooseAccount() {
    startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
}

private void setAccountName(String accountName) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
    editor.commit();
    credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
    this.accountName = accountName;
  }

private void onSignedIn() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.signedIn = true;

}

private void forgetAccount() {
    this.signedIn = false;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = settings.edit();
    editor2.remove(PREF_AUTH_TOKEN);
    editor2.commit();
  }
//end of account selection stuff

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_promoter_registration);

    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(this, "server:client_id:694163602530-ims6avatrar9aagbhg6gu7ke0p7458pa.apps.googleusercontent.com");
    setAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));

    Promoterendpoint.Builder builder = new Promoterendpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential);
    service = builder.build();

    if (credential.getSelectedAccountName() != null){
        onSignedIn();
    }

    //Place button here


    regBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View regBut) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            CreateNewPromoter();

        }

    });



}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
        if (data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
            String accountName =           data.getExtras().getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
            if (accountName != null) {
                setAccountName(accountName);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                editor.commit();
                onSignedIn();
            }
        }
    }
}


}
```

Logcat:

```
05-31 13:28:20.860: D/dalvikvm(12545): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 69K, 2% free 8886K/8984K, paused 45ms, total 51ms
05-31 13:28:20.883: I/dalvikvm-heap(12545): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.217MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-31 13:28:20.915: D/dalvikvm(12545): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 12485K/12588K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
05-31 13:28:20.954: D/dalvikvm(12545): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 1% free 12485K/12588K, paused 12ms+1ms, total 41ms
05-31 13:28:21.821: D/libEGL(12545): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
05-31 13:28:22.094: D/libEGL(12545): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
05-31 13:28:22.118: D/libEGL(12545): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
05-31 13:28:22.250: D/OpenGLRenderer(12545): Enabling debug mode 0
05-31 13:28:27.688: I/dalvikvm(12545): Could not find method com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.newChooseAccountIntent, referenced from method com.theincrowd.PromoterRegistrationActivity.chooseAccount
05-31 13:28:27.696: W/dalvikvm(12545): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 47: Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/GoogleAccountCredential;.newChooseAccountIntent ()Landroid/content/Intent;
05-31 13:28:27.696: D/dalvikvm(12545): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
05-31 13:28:27.696: I/dalvikvm(12545): Could not find method com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.setSelectedAccountName, referenced from method com.theincrowd.PromoterRegistrationActivity.setAccountName
05-31 13:28:27.696: W/dalvikvm(12545): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 48: Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/GoogleAccountCredential;.setSelectedAccountName (Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/GoogleAccountCredential;
05-31 13:28:27.696: D/dalvikvm(12545): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0010
05-31 13:28:27.696: W/dalvikvm(12545): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/theincrowd/promoterendpoint/model/Promoter; (53)
05-31 13:28:27.696: W/dalvikvm(12545): Link of class 'Lcom/theincrowd/promoterendpoint/model/Promoter;' failed
05-31 13:28:27.696: E/dalvikvm(12545): Could not find class 'com.theincrowd.promoterendpoint.model.Promoter', referenced from method com.theincrowd.PromoterRegistrationActivity.CreateNewPromoter
05-31 13:28:27.696: W/dalvikvm(12545): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 189 (Lcom/theincrowd/promoterendpoint/model/Promoter;) in Lcom/theincrowd/PromoterRegistrationActivity;
05-31 13:28:27.696: D/dalvikvm(12545): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
05-31 13:28:27.696: I/dalvikvm(12545): Could not find method com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience, referenced from method com.theincrowd.PromoterRegistrationActivity.onCreate
05-31 13:28:27.696: W/dalvikvm(12545): VFY: unable to resolve static method 49: Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/GoogleAccountCredential;.usingAudience (Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/GoogleAccountCredential;
05-31 13:28:27.696: D/dalvikvm(12545): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000b
05-31 13:28:27.696: W/dalvikvm(12545): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/theincrowd/promoterendpoint/model/Promoter; (53)
05-31 13:28:27.696: W/dalvikvm(12545): Link of class 'Lcom/theincrowd/promoterendpoint/model/Promoter;' failed
05-31 13:28:27.696: D/dalvikvm(12545): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0695 at 0x02 in Lcom/theincrowd/PromoterRegistrationActivity;.CreateNewPromoter
05-31 13:28:27.696: D/dalvikvm(12545): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x004e at 0x25 in Lcom/theincrowd/PromoterRegistrationActivity;.onCreate
05-31 13:28:27.696: W/dalvikvm(12545): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/theincrowd/promoterendpoint/Promoterendpoint$Builder; (44)
05-31 13:28:27.696: W/dalvikvm(12545): Link of class 'Lcom/theincrowd/promoterendpoint/Promoterendpoint$Builder;' failed
05-31 13:28:27.704: D/dalvikvm(12545): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0599 at 0x2a in Lcom/theincrowd/PromoterRegistrationActivity;.onCreate
05-31 13:28:27.704: D/AndroidRuntime(12545): Shutting down VM
05-31 13:28:27.704: W/dalvikvm(12545): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416bd930)
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.theincrowd/com.theincrowd.PromoterRegistrationActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545):    at com.theincrowd.PromoterRegistrationActivity.<init>(PromoterRegistrationActivity.java:41)
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
05-31 13:28:27.766: E/AndroidRuntime(12545):    ... 11 more
05-31 13:36:11.032: I/dalvikvm(13422): Could not find method com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.newChooseAccountIntent, referenced from method com.theincrowd.PromoterRegistrationActivity.chooseAccount
05-31 13:36:11.032: W/dalvikvm(13422): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 47: Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/GoogleAccountCredential;.newChooseAccountIntent ()Landroid/content/Intent;
05-31 13:36:11.032: D/dalvikvm(13422): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
05-31 13:36:11.032: I/dalvikvm(13422): Could not find method com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.setSelectedAccountName, referenced from method com.theincrowd.PromoterRegistrationActivity.setAccountName
05-31 13:36:11.032: W/dalvikvm(13422): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 48: Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/GoogleAccountCredential;.setSelectedAccountName (Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/GoogleAccountCredential;
05-31 13:36:11.032: D/dalvikvm(13422): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0010
05-31 13:36:11.040: W/dalvikvm(13422): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/theincrowd/promoterendpoint/model/Promoter; (53)
05-31 13:36:11.040: W/dalvikvm(13422): Link of class 'Lcom/theincrowd/promoterendpoint/model/Promoter;' failed
05-31 13:36:11.040: E/dalvikvm(13422): Could not find class 'com.theincrowd.promoterendpoint.model.Promoter', referenced from method com.theincrowd.PromoterRegistrationActivity.CreateNewPromoter
05-31 13:36:11.040: W/dalvikvm(13422): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 189 (Lcom/theincrowd/promoterendpoint/model/Promoter;) in Lcom/theincrowd/PromoterRegistrationActivity;
05-31 13:36:11.040: D/dalvikvm(13422): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
05-31 13:36:11.040: I/dalvikvm(13422): Could not find method com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience, referenced from method com.theincrowd.PromoterRegistrationActivity.onCreate
05-31 13:36:11.040: W/dalvikvm(13422): VFY: unable to resolve static method 49: Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/GoogleAccountCredential;.usingAudience (Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/GoogleAccountCredential;
05-31 13:36:11.040: D/dalvikvm(13422): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000b
05-31 13:36:11.040: W/dalvikvm(13422): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/theincrowd/promoterendpoint/model/Promoter; (53)
05-31 13:36:11.040: W/dalvikvm(13422): Link of class 'Lcom/theincrowd/promoterendpoint/model/Promoter;' failed
05-31 13:36:11.040: D/dalvikvm(13422): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0695 at 0x02 in Lcom/theincrowd/PromoterRegistrationActivity;.CreateNewPromoter
05-31 13:36:11.047: D/dalvikvm(13422): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x004e at 0x25 in Lcom/theincrowd/PromoterRegistrationActivity;.onCreate
05-31 13:36:11.047: W/dalvikvm(13422): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/theincrowd/promoterendpoint/Promoterendpoint$Builder; (44)
05-31 13:36:11.047: W/dalvikvm(13422): Link of class 'Lcom/theincrowd/promoterendpoint/Promoterendpoint$Builder;' failed
05-31 13:36:11.047: D/dalvikvm(13422): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0599 at 0x2a in Lcom/theincrowd/PromoterRegistrationActivity;.onCreate
05-31 13:36:11.047: D/AndroidRuntime(13422): Shutting down VM
05-31 13:36:11.047: W/dalvikvm(13422): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416bd930)
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.theincrowd/com.theincrowd.PromoterRegistrationActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422):    at com.theincrowd.PromoterRegistrationActivity.<init>(PromoterRegistrationActivity.java:41)
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
05-31 13:36:11.063: E/AndroidRuntime(13422):    ... 11 more
05-31 13:36:13.407: I/Process(13422): Sending signal. PID: 13422 SIG: 9
```

I hope this helps...

edit: Adding Manifest file.

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
    android:name="com.theincrowd.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.theincrowd.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.theincrowd.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.theincrowd.GCMIntentService" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.theincrowd" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.theincrowd" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.theincrowd.RegisterActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.theincrowd.PromoForkActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_promo_fork" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.theincrowd.PromoterRegistrationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_promoter_registration" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.theincrowd.PartyGoerDashActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_party_goer_dash" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.theincrowd.PartyListTabs"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_party_list_tabs" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Would you share your activity code and your logcat?

Comment: Your problem is `NullPointerException`. See `Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo` line. Include your `AndroidManifest.xml` as well. 

For the problem you mentioned in question, I think you should use `import com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker;` and also make sure you have Google Play Service imported to your project.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. I added that AccountPicker import and I had already import the google play services project into the project tree and made a reference to it. Do i need to import it into the activity?

Comment: One more thing: You are accessing your `EditText`s and reading their values before `onCreate`. They are all `null` if I'm not mistaken. Put all those line below `//text fields and button stuff` in `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of these lines must be in `onCreate` method:

**Tip**: *Someone has already told you where to put the buttons*. See `//Place button here` in your code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    //text fields and button stuff [FROM HERE]
    EditText fn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstName); 
    EditText ln = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastName);
    EditText org = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Button regBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regButton);
```

For the below lines you may just leave the declarations like this:

```
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String organization;
private String emailAddress;
```

And then again in `onCreate`, after you cast your views to `EditText`, you can read their values like this:

```
firstName = fn.getText().toString();
lastName = ln.getText().toString();
organization = org.getText().toString();
emailAddress = email.getText().toString();
```

Comment: I have moved around the code and made the changes you suggested. However, I'm still getting the force close.

Comment: @kreshendo, delete the `gen` folder. Clean your project and build again. Check logcat to see if you're getting the same error.

Comment: yeah its the same error. I think it has to do with the setAccountName() method that gets called in onCreate(). I did a bit of research on that NullPointerException but from looking at the code, i can't really tell which value is null at runtime.